# Slim framework Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Cannot create LogWriter

Tags: php, google-app-engine, slim

I recently started using Slim framework. I am currently attempting to authenticate using Middleware. This is the where the middleware is called:

```
$app->post('/profile', 'authenticate', function () {
     // code here
}
```

This is where my middleware takes care of the authentication:

```
function authenticate(\Slim\Route $route) {
    // Getting request headers
    $headers = apache_request_headers();
    $response = array();
    $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();

    // Verifying Authorization Header
    if (isset($headers['Authorization'])) {
        $db = new DbHandler();

        // get the api key
        $api_key = $headers['Authorization'];
        // validating api key
        if (!$db->isValidApiKey($api_key)) {
            // api key is not present in users table
            $response["error"] = true;
            $response["message"] = "Access Denied. Invalid Api key";
            echoRespnse(401, $response);
            $app->stop();
        } else {
            global $user_id;
            // get user primary key id
            $user_id = $db->getUserId($api_key);
        }
    } else {
        // api key is missing in header
        $response["error"] = true;
        $response["message"] = "Api key is misssing";
        echoRespnse(400, $response);
        $app->stop();
    }
};
```

I receive this error when I attempt the POST call. Other calls not requiring authentication all work correctly.

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Cannot create LogWriter. Invalid resource handle.' in D:\Liftmo\Liftmo.com\api\Slim\LogWriter.php:60 Stack trace: #0 D:\Liftmo\Liftmo.com\api\Slim\Slim.php(191): Slim\LogWriter->__construct(false) #1 D:\Liftmo\Liftmo.com\api\Slim\Helper\Set.php(228): Slim\Slim->Slim{closure}(Object(Slim\Helper\Set)) #2 D:\Liftmo\Liftmo.com\api\Slim\Helper\Set.php(88): Slim\Helper\Set->Slim\Helper{closure}(Object(Slim\Helper\Set)) #3 D:\Liftmo\Liftmo.com\api\Slim\Helper\Set.php(185): Slim\Helper\Set->get('logWriter') #4 D:\Liftmo\Liftmo.com\api\Slim\Slim.php(196): Slim\Helper\Set->offsetGet('logWriter') #5 D:\Liftmo\Liftmo.com\api\Slim\Helper\Set.php(228): Slim\Slim->Slim{closure}(Object(Slim\Helper\Set)) #6 D:\Liftmo\Liftmo.com\api\Slim\Helper\Set.php(88): Slim\Helper\Set->Slim\Helper{closure}(Object(Slim\Helper\Set)) #7 D:\Liftmo\Liftmo.com\api\Slim\Slim.php(234): Slim\Helper\Set->get('log') #8 D:\Liftmo\Liftmo.com\api\Slim\Slim.php(402): Slim\Slim->__get('log') in D:\Liftmo\Liftmo.com\api\Slim\LogWriter.php on line 60

I've run through the code line by line and it seems the issue lies with the line

```
$db = new DbHandler();
```

I'm pretty confused though because the class was used without issue everywhere else in my code.

```
require_once 'include/DbHandler.php'; // DbHandler included here at the top
```

I'd really appreciate it if someone could help me out. I took the authentication from [HERE](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/01/how-to-create-rest-api-for-android-app-using-php-slim-and-mysql-day-23/). Literally could not find this issue resolved anywhere. Using Google App Engine with Cloud SQL to deploy.

Comment: where exactly do you include the `DbHandler.php` file?

Comment: `index.php` (the contents of the file in the post) lies in a folder called api which is on the root of the project. Within api, there is a folder called 'include' which contains `DbHandler.php`

Comment: Please provide the part of the code where you create/configure the log writer

Comment: I don't create/configure it. That's why I'm confused.

Comment: That's strange, because by default, Slim writes all errors to `php://stderr`.
Have you done anything to your PHP configuration?

Comment: Nope. The PHP configurration (php.ini) is the default set by Google App Engine.

Comment: I have no experience with the google app engine, but I **guess** you can't write to `php://stderr`. You could try with just a simple script and check if you get the same or similar error.

Comment: Yes. Thanks. That was the issue. I don't have write permissions anywhere so I disabled logging. The issue still persists though because certain headers don't work for some reason. `Authorization` among them even though it's not stated in App Engine documentation.

Comment: According to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging you have write access to `/var/log/app_engine/custom_logs`, maybe try setting the correct path for the logger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue in my app, and i found this two tips that helped a lot:

1. Set the google_app_engine.disable_readonly_filesystem = 1 property in php.ini file stored in the root of your app. reference--> https://gae-php-tips.appspot.com/2015/03/
2. Use a diferent way than deafault to handle logging, to be able to see which part of your code or database have the problem. I found a great advice of how to do it in: https://leolutz.com/2014/11/slim-framework-on-google-app-engine/

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

See comments of question:

There is no write access to `php://stderr` with the Google App Engine.

According to https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/logging, write access is available in `/var/log/app_engine/custom_logs`. (Have not tried myself)